# JQuery children().find(x) returns bad result - prevObject

Tags: javascript, jquery, find

Why do I can't get required result from this code:

```
element.children().find('ul').first();
```

It returns prevObject.

When I use:

```
element.children('ul')
```

It works well. I dont understand what the difference is.

My html is like this:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>adssfsdf</li>
        <li>dfdfghdfh</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

You can see that problem at [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aezyjgtt/) .

Comment: The find will search only descendant elements.. not ancestor elements..

Comment: when you say `$('div').children().find('ul')` you are trying to find a `ul` which is a descendant of a element which is a child of a `div` element

Comment: I think what you need is `element.children('ul');`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/d27e5gwm/1/

Answer (score 1):

`find` searches for descendants that match the selector. `children` searches for children that match the selector. Say you have this tree:

```
A -> B -> C -> D
```

Then,

```
$(".A").children() // B

$(".A").find() // B, C, D

$(".A").children().find() // C, D
```

Why does the last one find only `C` and `D`? Because it searches the descendants of the children.

In your case - you first get the children, then search for the descendants of those children that are `ul`. But the children have no descendants, and you get no results. When you do `.children('ul')`, you are looking for children who are `ul` - and there is indeed one such.

Answer (score 0):

From the [jquery docs](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

> .find( selector )
>
> Description: Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

So `element.find('ul')` gets all the `ul` children of `element`

If you want to get `ul` using `find`

you should say

```
element.find('ul').first();
```

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aezyjgtt/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Check the children and find functions clearly here. i have mentioned the comments as well.

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>adssfsdf</li>
        <li>dfdfghdfh</li>
    </ul>
</div> 

$('div').children('ul').css({'color':'red'});  // children ul inside div
$('div').children('ul:first').css({'color':'red'}); // first ul inside div
$('div').find('ul').css({'color':'blue'}); // ul inside div
$('div').children('ul').find('li:first').css({'color':'green'}); // first li of ul inside div
```

check her also: https://jsfiddle.net/aezyjgtt/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
element.children().find('ul').first()
as per your html 
element.children() return the ul element  
element.children().find('ul') return nothing as you are finding the ul inside ul element
Because of this your css is not applying.
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aezyjgtt/6/)